# weirdness when packaging with xcrun (codesign fails when using variable)

Tags: ios, xcode, bash, cordova, build

I try to parameterize my application build script when running into this behaviour:
the app already has been build (with 'cordova build ios --release') and is available.

when calling:

```
   $ xcrun ... -sign "iPhone Developer: XXX" -embed ...
```

everything goes fine. so far so good :)
now i instead want to use a variable in the call like:

```
   $ identity="iPhone Developer: XXX" 
   $ xcrun ... -sign $identity  -embed ...
```

where i later pass the $identity parameter to my build script

doing the 'xcrun ...' like above logically results in the fact that the 'codesign' command only gets "iPhone" as parameter and fails (of course:)

thus i'm trying to mask the $identity

closest call for success is to use

```
   $ xcrun ... -sign \""$identity"\"  -embed ...
```

which results into a 'codesign' call by the xcrun like

```
   $ xcrun ... -sign \""$identity"\"  -embed ...
   [...]
   /usr/bin/codesign ... --sign "iPhone Developer: XXX" ...
   Program /usr/bin/codesign returned 1 : ["iPhone Developer: XXX": no identity found
]
```

interestingly enough executing the command directly from shell (/bin/bash) works okay !!?

i tried as well to define $identity already having double-quotes but that runs into the initial behaviour with no quotation at all. using single-quotes in various combinations didn't help either so far.

any idea why xcrun is getting it wrong ? ... or, how to do it differently?
like said: the goal is to have a parameterized build script

-------- system parameters ---------
$ uname -a
Darwin allianz 13.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

$ xcrun -version
xcrun version 22.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this weirdness seems to be due to the fact that I assembled the command line like

```
   xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageAppliction $package -o $ipafile -sign \"$identity
\" -embed $profile
```

doing it the way to assemble the parts (option1 $variable1 option2 $variable2 ... etc.) to just one string first, like

```
   assembledstring="-sdk iphoneos PackageAppliction $package -o $ipafile -sign \"$identity
\" -embed $profile"
```

and only then doing a

```
   sh -c "xcrun $assemledstring"
```

sorts the issue.

Comment: Or use:
`$(xcrun --sdk iphoneos --find PackageAppliction) $package -o ...`